# Help with initial value problem

Tags: integration

Solve the initial-value problem

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1−\sin(5x)}{\cos(5x)+5x+6}\qquad x > -1$$

$y=3$ when $x=0$.

Can anyone please help me with this and show me the steps required to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that the top of the fraction is a fifth of the derivative of the bottom and that:

$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\:\mathrm{d}x=\ln(f(x))+c$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Multiply and divide the rhs by $5$. This leads to $$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{1}{5} \frac{5−5\sin(5x)}{\cos(5x)+5x+6}$$ Now, what is numerator with respect to the denominator ?

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. I am afraid I am still completely stuck on this. I think my brain is fried and over thinking everything! Can you please advise me a little further. Thanks